# WinRT ItemsControl with Grid columns and rows

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, itemscontrol

I'm new to XAML. I searched about ItemsControl and I found a tutorial, which is easy to understand, but the problem is that it is not work in WinRT.

Tutorial: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/

I tried to use `TargetType` in `Style` tag, however, in runtime I got an exception.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                Value="{Binding xIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                Value="{Binding yIndex}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox  Background="{Binding color}" Text="{Binding xIndex,Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Please add details of the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
```

this is what is should be:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
```

The `ItemContainer` for an `ItemsControl` is a `ContentPresenter` (unless a specific item is added to the `ItemsControl`).

So your view hierarchy looks something like this (assuming you didn't change the `ItemsPanel` to something other than a `StackPanel`):

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter>
        <TextBox/>
    </ContentPresenter>
</StackPanel>
```

Edit:

As Scott pointed out in the comments, this solution doesn't actually work for WinRT.  I did something similar and you can probably modify it to do the appropriate binding:

```
public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        FrameworkElement source = element as FrameworkElement;
        if (source != null)
        {
            source.SetBinding(Canvas.LeftProperty, new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("X"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
            source.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Y"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
        }
    }
}
```

This binds the `Canvas.LeftProperty` to the `X` property on each item in the collection and similarly the `Canvas.TopProperty` and the `Y` property.

Comment: It is run without exception, but it is not use the column and row property yet.

Comment: Now im using a canvas with margins on each element, however it is not what I really want, if my problem is not clear, I can show more code.

Comment: `Margins` don't work in a canvas.  You need to do something like `Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30"` to set the absolute position of your controls within the canvas.

Comment: Could u show me a working winrt project, because it can't work to me with grid binding.

Comment: Does your `Grid` have rows and columns?

Comment: Yes, but I read that, setter bindint is not supported in winrt, and sl, only in wpf. I found a blog post in the field, which is working in sl. Unfortunately it is not working in rt:S:D

Comment: Here is the link if u are interested in:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what you're talking about and I don't have time at the moment to read that post.

Comment: The OP requested a solution for WinRT Xaml. @mydogisbox provided a solution that would work for the equivalent xaml in WPF or Silverlight. Unfortunately this does not work in WinRT

Comment: @ScottFerguson You're right.  I added a new solution which I think can be modified to do the appropriate thing.